# Почему не изменяются стили второго элемента при наведении на первый элемент?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Не могу сообразить почему не изменяется стиль второго элемента при hover на первый элемент... Вроде написано всё правильно, но не работает, обновлял и чистил кэш браузера, всё равно не работает... подскажите пожалуйста.

```css
.info_block{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .85em;
    background: rgba(45, 5, 113, 0.8);
    color: white;
}
.info{
    cursor: help;
}
   .info:hover .info_block{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <h4>Информация <i class="far fa-question-circle info">111</i></h4>
    <div>
       <div class="info_block">
           <i class="fas fa-info-circle mr-1"></i> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [CSS-селекторы и комбинаторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) — см. как это в принципе работает

Answer (score 3):

При указании селекторов через пробел, элемент будет искаться **внутри**.

Таким образом, селектор

```
.info:hover .info_block
```

выберет элементы `.info_block`, которые находятся **внутри** элемента с классом `.info`. Так как в разметке `.info_block` находится в другом элементе - стили и не применяются.

Для указанной разметки невозможно связать данные элементы стилями только с помощью css. Нужно использовать `javascript` и события [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event), [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) для ручной реализации `:hover`

Comment: Добавил css-решение для этого конкретного примера.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, как обходной путь пойдет, до момента, пока hover не понадобится самому h4 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy!

```css
.info_block{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .85em;
    background: rgba(45, 5, 113, 0.8);
    color: white;
}

h4 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.info{
    cursor: help;
    pointer-events:auto;
}

h4:hover + div > .info_block {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h4>Информация <i class="far fa-question-circle info">111</i></h4>
    <div>
       <div class="info_block">
           <i class="fas fa-info-circle mr-1"></i> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
       </div>
    </div>
```

P.S. В данном примере разметки предлагаю вешать :hover не на вложенный элемент, а на весь заголовок целиком, но отменить все действия мыши (pointer-events) над ним. Для вложенного элемента .info возвращаем pointer-events — в результате :hover сработает только над ним, и у нас останется возможность использовать соседний селектор (+): `h4:hover + div > .info_block`